# My firebase user object doesn't seem to be right

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm newbie to firebase.

I'm trying to make a signup component using firebase authentication, but the user object I've got returned from firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword doesn't seem to be right.

The official document says that I can get the uid by calling user.uid, but in my case it returns null. Instead, I can get uid by calling user.user.uid.
I'm so confused.

Is the document I'v seen was outdated? or have I done something wrong?

Detailed codes are below. Please take a look and give me a piece of advice.

```
const promise=firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
promise
.then((user) => {
 console.log(user);
 console.log(user.id); //returns null
 console.log(user.user.uid); //returns O6hLcfJL5NT4fV2S7JprQ3MhjCK2, which I assumes to be uid.
})
.catch((e) => {
 console.log(e.message);
})
```

Following are the result of console.log(user).

```
{user: P, credential: null, additionalUserInfo: Wf, operationType: "signIn"}
 additionalUserInfo: Wf {providerId: "password", isNewUser: true}
 credential: null
 operationType: "signIn"
 user: P {G: Array(0), l: "AIzaSyDIj8N9kONUkpOdMGuApNcKkaeFYYEzfyk", o: "[DEFAULT]", u: "bluegenie-2ba45.firebaseapp.com", c: bi, …}
 __proto__: Object
```

As you can see, there is another user object inside the user object which I've got returned from createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#createuserwithemailandpassword) returns a promise that resolves with a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#usercredential) instead of a User.

This change was made in [v5.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_380_-_april_18_2017)